# update query with case statement giving missing keyword error

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, sql-update, case

There are 2 tables `INFO` and `ADDR`
`ADDR` has 4 columns `ID, LINE_1_ADDR, LINE_2_ADDR, TEMP_ADDR_ID` 
`INFO` has 4 columns `ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, ADDR_ID` 
I want to replace the data in `INFO.ADDR_ID` with `ADDR.ID` whenever there is a match of `INFO.ADDR_ID` and `ADDR.TEMP_ADDR_ID`

I have the following UPDATE query which is giving error

> ORA-00905: missing keyword

Below is my code:

```
UPDATE INFO SET INFO.ADDR_ID = (CASE
WHEN ADDR.TEMP_ADDR_ID = INFO.ADDR_ID
THEN INFO.ADDR_ID = ADDR.ID
END);
```

I am new to SQL queries involving case, don't know where it's wrong. Any help please !

Thanks

Comment: is ADDR other table ?

Comment: Yes ADDR is the other table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you using MYSQL

```
 UPDATE INFO 
 INNER JOIN ADRR ON ADDR.TEMP_ADDR_ID = INFO.ADDR_ID
 SET INFO.ADDR_ID = ADDR.ID
```

If you using ORACLE

use this

```
UPDATE INFO SET INFO.ADDR_ID = (SELECT ADRR.ID
                                FROM ADRR  
                                WHERE ADDR.TEMP_ADDR_ID = INFO.ADDR_ID)
```

Comment: I am not too sure but the `UPDATE` is expecting a `SET` before a `JOIN`. It gives an error, missing `SET` keyword !

Comment: I tried on TOAD and it seems to give error, `ORA-00971: missing SET keyword`

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** After getting more info, echo_Me's approach is the right one for the update.

```
UPDATE INFO 
JOIN ADDR ON /*your Join condition*/
SET INFO.ADDR_ID = ADDR.ID
```

Comment: I am getting this error after trying the above code. Thanks.
`ORA-00904: "ADDR"."ID": invalid identifier`